# Est-ce que c'est un erreur ou un dicton: "a été quitte pour un avertissement" en lieu de "quitté"?

Tags: grammaire

De *L'Étranger* par Albert Camus

> La veille nous étions allés au commissariat et j'avais témoigné que la
>   fille avait «manqué» à Raymond. Il en a été **quitte** pour un
>   avertissement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

non ce n'est pas une erreur, "en être quitte pour" est une locution qui veut dire "n'avoir à subir que l'inconvénient de". Or in english: "to get off with something"